# How to work with Spring Data's Optional<Object> Returns

Tags: hibernate, java-8, spring-data

We have a patchwork of Hibernate-gnerated domain objects, e.g.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "events_t", schema = "public")
public class EventsT implements java.io.Serializable {    
    private int id;
    private RecallsT recallsT; // another table
}
```

With Spring Data, I can't do

```
RecallsT recallsT = recallsDAO.findById(recallId);
```

I'm forced to do

```
Optional<RecallsT> recallsT = recallsDAO.findById(recallId);
```

but this introduces another issue: now I can't use my Hibernate objects anymore, because this won't work:

```
eventsT.setRecallsT(recallsT);
```

Now the error will be that it can't fit an "Optional<...>" object into a plain Object. As I showed in the Hibernate entity, the setter takes a straight plain object because of the traditional way our domain objects were generated.

What to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can write instead

```
recallsT.ifPresent(eventsT::setRecallsT);
```

Optional represents possible absence of data, and has methods to work with this wrapper.
More info about correct usage of optional [is here.](http://www.baeldung.com/java-optional)

Comment: :: ? Is this C++ or something? is this valid in Java?

Comment: It's java 8 syntax for method reference - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

Comment: And if I write my own @Query findByXX() methods, they also have to return Optional? Because the custom ones I can write to return the plain Object, and there's no problem with that, it's actually clearer like that. I wonder if I should create manual stubs for everything that returns a plain Object...

Comment: @geneb. You are not forced to write your custom methods with Optional, you can use plain object and `null` will indicate absence of data. More info about spring data's repository return methods you can find in the documentation - https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-return-types

Answer (score 1):

You can also write:

```
  private Todo findTodoEntryById(Long id) {
        Optional<Todo> todoResult = repository.findOne(id);
        return todoResult.orElseThrow(() -> new TodoNotFoundException(id));
}
```